# Кэширование в PHP: 2 БД, 1 удаленная

Tags: кэширование, php, mysql

Всем привет.

Работаю сейчас с сайтиком, в нем происходит следующее:

Есть БД с деталями на удаленном сервере (около 80ГБ, куча линковочных таблиц, несколько языков), есть БД с "товарами", которые по сути являются записями вида "артикул, бренд, цена" и служат для добавления цены к детали, ну и дальнейших операций с ними.

Гадость в том, что удаленная база огромна и соответственно в среднем страница грузится около 15-20 сек. Перенести к себе возможности не имею. Т.е. теоретически она есть, но, во-первых, пинг до нее меньше 0.3 сек, а во-вторых, я не думаю, что смогу предложить ей более мощный сервер.

Оптимизировать запросы - не уверен, что есть смысл. Банальное `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE article='AD32401S'"` выполняется около 5 сек, а они там 1-2-страничные.

Может ли кто-нибудь предложить способы ускорения этого дела? Сейчас все принудительно кэшируется на год (база все равно обновляется редко и в этом случае проще почистить кэш). Есть призрачная надежда выкупить базу и поднять ее на одном VPS с сайтом, стоит ли пробовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все элементарно ( вряд-ли тебе подойдет, но суть уловишь ), весь функционал который так или иначе работает с изменяющимися данными (сессии, cookie и т.д.) переносищь на ajax. Если у тебя frontend сервер не nginx - ставишь. Настраиваешь проксирование php с nginx на apache, должным образом меняешь конфигурацию виртуального хоста(ов). Выставляешь кеширование результата выполнения для всех php скриптов не относящихся к ajax( читай динамическому функционалу ).

По поводу выкупить базу и поднять на VPS - а что это изменит? Тут нужно проанализировать и сделать правильные выводы, вполне возможно что ощутимого прироста это не принесет, возможно действительно - это корень всех бед, но тут не гадать надо. Хотя, конечно, если такой возможности нет - то тут только пальцем в небо (ну а то, что так делать не надо, думаю писать не стоит)

Еще есть вариант (при наличии достаточного количества ОП, кароче барское предложение, вряд-ли у тебя есть столько ОП xD, но тем не менее...) - создавать таблицу(ы) на движке memory и работать с ней(ними), ну и периодически обновлять ее(их) cron'ом.

В любом случае, так или иначе - варианта 2:

- больше выжимаешь из сервера
- кешируешь все, что только можно

PS: если нужны какие-то более экзотические предложения - уточни вопрос (напиши подробнее о сайте, количестве данных и т.д. и т.п., пофантазирую).

Comment: Так вот ботлнек как раз в запросах) Если я закеширую все что можно, я добьюсь максимального прироста вроде 15.9s --> 15.6s. Пока это, скажем так, не требуется. 

Проверил, полная генерация страницы:

    Запрос на поиск:     18.82316493988
    Повтор запроса (F5)   0.00289106369

И дополнительно: 5 сек происходит один только коннект. Как выяснилось, с пингом я вполне могу соврать, ибо сервер в Германии)

Comment: ну так в чем тогда вопрос? О_о

Если 5 сек происходит один только коннект - тогда конечно нужно брать сервере и переносить

Только вот 5 это все-равно "долговато"

Comment: Вопрос в том, является ли удаленность критерием скорости, с учетом того, что в базе 77 таблиц и около 80 гб данных, а в запросах редко бывает меньше 5 джойнов.

Пинг проверил: 40мс в среднем =/ Но естественно это не говорит о самом серваке mysql.

Просто брать сервак - это надо будет ребятам объяснять, почему вместо $10 они будут $50 отдавать за VPS-ку, а если выигрыша в скорости не будет - я получу по ушам)

*Фак, как нуб изъясняюсь =( Надо больше с людьми общаться, наверно*